# Calling a simple method in C++ from machine code result in segmentation fault

Tags: c++, assembly, machine-code

So I am trying to write a simple program that call a simple method from machine code in C++, and the target platform is Windows x86-64. Here is the reproducible code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

void test(long long int val) {
    std::cout << "Calling test function:" << val << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    unsigned char code[] = {
            // Load the address of the target into RAX register.
            0x48, 0xB8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, // mov rax, imm64
            0x48, 0xB9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, // mov rcx, imm64
            0xFF, 0xD0, // call rax
            0xC3 // ret
    };

    // Simulation of test(12345);

    *((void **) &code[2]) = (void *) &test; // Pass the address of the function.
    *((long long int *) &code[12]) = 12345L; // Pass the argument.

    // Preparation
    SYSTEM_INFO sys_info;
    GetSystemInfo(&sys_info);
    auto const page_size = sys_info.dwPageSize;
    auto const code_buffer = VirtualAlloc(nullptr, page_size, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    ::memcpy(code_buffer, code, sizeof(code));

    using func_ptr_t = void (*)();
    auto const func_ptr = reinterpret_cast<func_ptr_t>(code_buffer);
    func_ptr();
    VirtualFree(code_buffer, 0, MEM_RELEASE);

    return 0;
}
```

So what this does is just printing our the string "Calling test function: 12345", but I have met with segmentation fault during the call of the function `void test(long long int)`.

[image: In debugger]

It is proved by the debugger that the function can be called successfully and the value of `val` is also passed correctly, yet the segmentation fault appears after this line.

Does anyone knows the cause of it and how to fix it?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you single-stepped the assembly code ?

Comment: Missing shadow space and misaligned stack. Use `sub rsp, 40` to adjust. Don't forget to undo it before returning.

Comment: @RichardCritten Do you mean that I can try converting this to use the keyword ```asm``` first with the assembly language representation to test?

Comment: Segfault on return can mean the return address on the stack was corrupted. As jester says, you are missing the shadow space

Comment: No most debuggers have a assembly/machine-code window and you can single-step each assembly instruction, inspect the registers etc.  So you can break on the call ` func_ptr();` switch to the assembly view and single-step each machine-code instruction.

Comment: @Jester Ohh thank you! It worked :) I want to know more about why using ```sub rsp, 40``` can deal with the shadow space?

Comment: The shadow space is 32 bytes. The extra 8 are for alignment. Consult [microsoft calling convention documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/stack-usage). They seem to call the shadow space _"register parameter stack area"_

Comment: If you tailcalled with `jmp rax`, instead of `call rax`/`ret`, you wouldn't need to mess with the stack.

Comment: It's part of the Microsoft x64 calling convention.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170   The Linux convention is slightly different.